# MVC4: Remove custom row on session end

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cross-domain, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I am creating an entry in a table for a users session which is mapped to a guid for cross domain access to an API. The row in the table looks like [guid, cookie] and is populated at login.

```
session.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
session.cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(sUser.email, false).Value;
```

The problem I'm having is removing this from the database when the session ends. I have this so far which doesn't seem to be working.

In Session_End():

```
var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
string cValue = cookie.Value;

using (var db = new xEntities())
{
     Session session = db.Sessions.Where(p => p.cookie == cValue).FirstOrDefault();
     db.Sessions.Remove(session);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a clunky alternative for the meantime:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Session session = new Session();
session.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
session.cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(sUser.email, false).Value;
session.started = now;

using (var db = new xEntities())
{
   db.Sessions.Add(session);
   db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = new xEntities())
{
   List<Session> sessions = db.Sessions.ToList();
   now = now.AddMinutes(-60);

   foreach(Session s in sessions)
   {
      if (s.started < now)
      {
         db.Sessions.Remove(s);
      }
   }
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```